# Forge Inventor Drawing PDF Export

Tags: autodesk-forge

What would be the best way to export PDF from Inventor drawing (IDW) written with iLogic Rules similar to Configurator 360 export? How to provide an external link for PDF download using forge APIs?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to use **Design Automation API for Inventor** to export an **IDW** to **PDF**.
Easiest might be to follow the instructions on the following website to create all the parts and then just modify the code of the **AppBundle** to simply **SaveAs**() the opened **IDW** to a **PDF**:
https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/modifymodels

1. Modify the **outputFile** parameter of the **Activity** to have **localName** as **outputFile.pdf** (or anything else, but it needs to match what the **AppBundle**'s code will use for **SaveAs**()) and **inputFile** to have **localName** something ending with "**.idw**"
2. Use this code in the **AppBundle**:

   ```
   public void Run(Document doc)
   {
     LogTrace("Run called");

     exportToPdf(doc);
   }

   public void exportToPdf(Document doc)
   {
     LogTrace("Saving to PDF");
     doc.SaveAs("outputFile.pdf", true);
     LogTrace("Done");
   }
   ```
3. When running the activity the **inputFile** should have a **URL** to the **IDW** file and **outputFile** should have a **URL** to a **PDF** file

Comment: Thanks Adam. It is possible using iLogic ?

Comment: Yes, you can use iLogic on DA. You can even send iLogic commands instead of creating an AppBundle, if that's what you want: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/run-ilogic-rule-without-appbundle